# Remove "labels" overlay on new Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

On the [old style](https://maps.google.co.uk/?output=classic) Google Maps there was an option to remove the "labels" overlay so in satellite view you would just see the map.

In the new version of Maps I can't seem to find out how to remove this layer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Updated September 2023]

1. Click the `Layers` box on the left bottom corner.
2. Click `More` on the far right of the pop-out menu.
3. Click `Satellite`.
4. Uncheck `Labels`.

Screenshots below for reference:

[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]

Answer (score 3):

### Stylized Google Maps

You can use the Google Maps Styled Map Wizard which allows to remove labels and do other sorts of personalizations (Roads, Landmarks, Color Styles, elements coloring and fill, etc):

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: Really not helpful for Satellite view.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be free.